# Google Seach API timeout error with VPN but fine on website

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to use google search API in my python code to get text input/output through jupyter notebook so I activate an Custom Search JSON API key and cx code. But due to network restriction, I'm running this code **on VPN PAC mode**

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "xx"
cse_id = "xx"
search_term = "xx"

service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)

res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id).execute()
```

and get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2628\1861807644.py in <module>
      7 service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
      8 
----> 9 res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id).execute()

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129                     logger.warning(message)
--> 130             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    131 
    132         return positional_wrapper

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    930             method=str(self.method),
    931             body=self.body,
--> 932             headers=self.headers,
    933         )
    934 

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    220         if exception:
    221             if retry_num == num_retries:
--> 222                 raise exception
    223             else:
    224                 continue

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py in _retry_request(http, num_retries, req_type, sleep, rand, uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    189         try:
    190             exception = None
--> 191             resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    192         # Retry on SSL errors and socket timeout errors.
    193         except _ssl_SSLError as ssl_error:

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1719                 else:
   1720                     (response, content) = self._request(
-> 1721                         conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,
   1722                     )
   1723         except Exception as e:

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1438             auth.request(method, request_uri, headers, body)
   1439 
-> 1440         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1441 
   1442         if auth:

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1360             try:
   1361                 if conn.sock is None:
-> 1362                     conn.connect()
   1363                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
   1364             except socket.timeout:

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py in connect(self)
   1196             break
   1197         if not self.sock:
-> 1198             raise socket_err
   1199 
   1200 

c:\users\fchen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py in connect(self)
   1150                 if has_timeout(self.timeout):
   1151                     sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
-> 1152                 sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
   1153 
   1154                 self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

but when I'm running it on the [website](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list):
[image]
it works fine(the VPN status was the same on PAC mode). What can I do to make it work in python code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code network does not go through a VPN，
test code

```py
import requests
requests.get(https://www.youtube.com/)
```

use agent model in VPN
and add follow code in you code

```py
import os
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:port"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:port"
```

use your VPN port in code
and test again

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but I got a ConnectionResetError. Does the IP address(127.0.0.1, those before the port) has to correspond with my VPN address/port/pswd? Do I have to open the VPN client with the exact same settings while using the proxies in the code? I've been confused about this for a long time...May I contact you privately for detailed instructions?

Comment: @fchen92 yes, you must use same param in your code and vpn,